# How to find a match between non ordered strings

Tags: r, string, mismatch

I have two data frames in R.
This is the first (just a sample):

```
ID  Cost        Vehicle_1
6   4291.667    FIAT PUNTO 1.4 EVO
2   5391.667    FIESTA 1.6 120CV 
4   4291.667    FIESTA 1.6 120CV 
7   3500.000    FIESTA 1.6 120CV 
5   4291.667    SEAT IBIZA 1.4 85CV
1   5391.667    SEAT IBIZA 85CV 1.4
```

This is the second (just a sample):

```
Vehicle_2                          cost
FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.3 MJT 95CV DPF    0.4021967    
FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.3/16V MJT 75CV    0.3737767    
FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.4 77CV     
FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.4 77CV BENZ+GPL   0.4036200    
FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.4 77CV BENZ+MET   0.4122800    
FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.4 M.AIR 105CV     0.4702500
```

I need to find the matches between the columns called Vehicle_1 of the first dataframe and and the column called Vehicle_2 of the second one, even if the strings are not in the same order and there are some words more/less. 
I tried with the function all.equal, but it doesn't print the results. In fact, I need to create a new table with the "matching elements".
thanks

Comment: Did you try `merge` or `match` functions? Also `intersect`....

Comment: Which rows are supposed to be matched? The text is quite different if I'm not mistaken. Should `FIAT PUNTO 1.4 EVO` be matched with row 3, 4,5 or 6 in the second df or with all? The question is not very clear. Maybe it would help if you added the expected output as a table to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following :

```
# Here is what your data looks like:
df1 <- data.frame("ID" = 1:6,
                  "Vehicle_1" = c("FIAT PUNTO 1.4 EVO",
                                  "FIESTA 1.6 120CV",
                                  "FIESTA 1.6 120CV",
                                  "FIESTA 1.6 120CV",
                                  "SEAT IBIZA 1.4 85CV",
                                  "SEAT IBIZA 85CV 1.4")) 

df2 <- data.frame("ID" = 1:6,
                  "Vehicle_2" = c("FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.3 MJT 95CV DPF",
                                  "FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.3/16V MJT 75CV",
                                  "FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.4 77CV",
                                  "FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.4 77CV ",
                                  "FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.4 77CV BENZ+GPL",
                                  "FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.4 M.AIR 105CV ")) 

head(df1)
head(df2)
```

```
ID           Vehicle_1
1  1  FIAT PUNTO 1.4 EVO
2  2    FIESTA 1.6 120CV
3  3    FIESTA 1.6 120CV
4  4    FIESTA 1.6 120CV
5  5 SEAT IBIZA 1.4 85CV
6  6 SEAT IBIZA 85CV 1.4
```

```
ID                        Vehicle_2
1  1  FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.3 MJT 95CV DPF
2  2  FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.3/16V MJT 75CV
3  3          FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.4 77CV
4  4         FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.4 77CV 
5  5 FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.4 77CV BENZ+GPL
6  6  FIAT PUNTO EVO 1.4 M.AIR 105CV
```

```
# I transform to data.table
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table::setDT(df1)
df2 <- data.table::setDT(df2)

# I use tstrplit to get the elements from both variables that are
# supposed to be matched
df3 <- df1[, tstrsplit(Vehicle_1, split = ' ')]
df4 <- df2[, tstrsplit(Vehicle_2, split = ' ')]

ncol1 <- ncol(df3)
df_to_check <- cbind(df3,df4)

list_result <- apply(df_to_check,MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x)
  intersect(x[1:ncol1], x[ncol1+1:length(x)]))

df1[, c("list_match") := list_result]
head(df1)
```

And here is the result, which I added to df1:

```
 ID           Vehicle_1     list_match
1:  1  FIAT PUNTO 1.4 EVO FIAT,PUNTO,EVO
2:  2    FIESTA 1.6 120CV             NA
3:  3    FIESTA 1.6 120CV             NA
4:  4    FIESTA 1.6 120CV             NA
5:  5 SEAT IBIZA 1.4 85CV            1.4
6:  6 SEAT IBIZA 85CV 1.4            1.4
```